# How to rerun the request handler in node + express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native

I am running node + express + mongojs. Here is a sample code:

```
function mongoCallback(req, res) {
  "use strict";
  return function (err, o) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(500, err.message);
    } else if (!o) {
      res.send(404);
    } else {
      res.send(o);
    }
  };
}

var express, app, params, mongo, db;

express = require('express');
params = require('express-params');
app = express();
params.extend(app);

app.use("/", express.static('web'));

mongo = require('mongojs');

db = mongo.connect('mydb', ['inventory']);

app.get('/api/inventory', function (req, res) {
  db.inventory.find(mongoCallback(req, res));
});

app.listen(8000);
console.log('Listening on port 8000');
```

Sometimes I forget running mongod and an attempt to talk to the database fails with "failed to connect to ..." error. The problem is that starting mongod is not enough, the already existing `db` object seems to remember that no connection could be made and so the server continues to fail, even if mongod is already running.

So, I have come up with the following solution:

```
var express, app, params, mongo, db, api;

if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) {
    "use strict";
    return this.lastIndexOf(str, 0) === 0;
  };
}

function setDB() {
  db = mongo.connect('IF', ['invoices', 'const', 'inventory']);
}

function mongoCallback(req, res, next, caller, secondTry) {
  return function (err, o) {
    if (err) {
      if (!secondTry && err.message && err.message.startsWith("failed to connect to")) {
        setDB();
        caller(req, res, next, true);
      } else {
        res.send(500, err.message);
      }
    } else if (!o) {
      res.send(404);
    } else {
      res.send(o);
    }
  };
}

express = require('express');
params = require('express-params');
app = express();
params.extend(app);

app.use("/", express["static"]('web'));

mongo = require('mongojs');

setDB();

api = {
  getInventory: function (req, res, next, secondTry) {
    db.inventory.find(mongoCallback(req, res, next, api.getInventory, secondTry));
  }
};

app.get('/api/inventory', api.getInventory);

app.listen(8000);
console.log('Listening on port 8000');
```

Basically it recreates the `db` object if a request fails with the "failed to connect to" error and reruns the request. This is done only for the first failure. A subsequent failure returns the error.

I do not like my solution at all. There has to be a better way. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "the already existing db object seems to remember that no connection could be made"?  Do you mean that the queries on the database fail if you start the express app before running mongod?  Since you are connecting to the DB at the startup of the express app, you should have the mongod running first.

If you are worried about the database going down after the initial connection and causing your CRUD operations to fail, you can check for an error in your operations

```
db.inventory.find(function(err, docs) {
    // check err to see if there was a connection issue
});
```

and then reconnect if there was an error.

Comment: "Do you mean that the queries on the database fail if you start the express app before running mongod?" - exactly. I know I should have mongod running before. The problem I sometimes forget to run it and I want to be able to start mongod without also restarting the server. "and then reconnect if there was an error" - isn't it what I already do? As I am saying in the question, I do not like the way I am doing it and looking for a better implementation. Can you propose one?

Comment: Can you set autoreconnect to true in the initial connection?  https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/docs/database.md

Comment: (since mongojs is a wrapper for node-mongodb-native)

Comment: mongojs does set `auto_reconect` to `true`, unlike node-mongodb-native. Still does not work.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in mongojs... have you tried using the raw node-mongodb-native api instead?

Comment: No, I have not. I just might. I wish I knew what is the added value of mongojs over the node-mongodb-native.

Comment: Apparently, the native driver's API is awkward, which is the reason for the existence of some many wrappers around it, mongojs being one of them.

Comment: I tested your code, and in your original example (without your fix), the reconnect does work if the original connection worked (bring up mongod, bring up express, kill mongod, bring mongod back up, reconnect works).  My advice would be, just write a script to start your application that starts the mongod instance before the express server, and only even start your application from this script.  That way you won't start your server without having mongod already running.

Comment: How would you then go about separating the mongodb and the server to be run on different machines?

Comment: The script could take that into account, by ssh-ing into the machines the mongod and server are on.

Comment: This becomes way too complicated. Doesn't it seem to you that `auto_complete` should simply work even if mongod was not running before?

Comment: It does.  Another idea: on the first connection to the DB (on express startup), print an error and quit if the connection doesn't work?  That would avoid the issue by making sure your first connection never fails silently.

Comment: Do you know how to reduce the timeout used by mongo before giving up talking to a downed database?

Comment: http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/database.html - My guess is either the "timeout" Socket Option, or a combination of the retryMilliseconds and numberOfRetries DB options.

Comment: Yep, `db.client.numberOfRetries = 5;` did it. The default is 60, 1sec apart (`db.client.retryMiliSeconds == 1000`).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the mongodb native driver allows to set `{ auto_reconnect:true }`, have you tried to set this?

I'm not sure how this behaves if the database wasn't running at all, `mongoose.js` for example caches all requests until the DB is ready and issues them after a successful connection.

Comment: This is interesting. However, I am unable to find the relevant documentation. Mind to provide a link?

Comment: And where do they talk about auto_reconnect?